# How can I reset i in for iteration after delete some rows | python

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, iteration

I have a iteration where I have deleted some rows, so I need that the iteration start again on row=1 to go through all the data again:

```
for i, row in enumerate(Proyectonevera2):
if Proyectonevera2.loc[i,'Clave'] == "P":
    CodIng = Proyectonevera2.loc[i,'Ingrediente']
    NuevoInv_Ing = Proyectonevera2.loc[i,'Nuevo Inventario']
if  (Proyectonevera2.loc[i,'Clave'] == "N" and Proyectonevera2.loc[i,'Ingrediente'] == CodIng):
    Proyectonevera2.loc[i,'Inv_Ing'] = NuevoInv_Ing
    if Proyectonevera2.loc[i,'Cant Ingr SUM'] !=0 and Proyectonevera2.loc[i,'Cant Prod SUM']!=0:
        Proyectonevera2.loc[i,'Cantidad producir']=Proyectonevera2.loc[i,'Inv_Ing']*Proyectonevera2.loc[i,'Cant Prod SUM']/Proyectonevera2.loc[j,'Cant Ingr SUM']
        dfc = Proyectonevera2.groupby('CodProducto')['Cantidad producir']
        Proyectonevera2.assign(min=dfc.transform(min))
        Proyectonevera2.loc[i,'Consumo Agosto'] = Proyectonevera2.loc[i,'min']*Proyectonevera2.loc[i,'Cant Ingr SUM']/Proyectonevera2.loc[i,'Cant Prod SUM']
        Proyectonevera2.loc[i,'Nuevo Inventario'] = Proyectonevera2.loc[i,'Inv_Ing']-Proyectonevera2.loc[i,'Consumo Agosto']
        bdnevera = Proyectonevera2[Proyectonevera2['Clave']=="P"]
        nevera.append(bdnevera) 
        Proyectonevera2= Proyectonevera2.drop(Proyectonevera2[Proyectonevera2['Clave']=="P"].index)
        Proyectonevera2 = Proyectonevera2.reset_index(drop=True)
        for j, row in enumerate(Proyectonevera2):
            Codprod = Proyectonevera2.loc[1,'CodProducto']
            if Proyectonevera2.loc[j,'CodProducto'] == Codprod:
                Proyectonevera2.loc[j,'Clave'] = "P"
```

How can I do it? thanks

Comment: Its hard to spot the problem in this code. Consider writing a simple running example of just the thing you are interested in. Variable names like "foo" and "bar" instead of "Proyecttomevera2" help.

Comment: Those first two `if`'s. The second is exclusive of the first, so it should be an `elif` and the first doesn't do anything, so it shouldn't be there at all ... so maybe the second `if` should stay that way. Pandas is good at broadcasting operations across the entire table. You loop and do `.loc` a lot but one of the goals of pandas is to avoid loops.